# Scraping using 'elementbyID' how to return value of 0 when ID doesn't exist?

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

Hello I have some code below that scrape's data off a website.

What I am struggling with is the Element id doesn't *always* exist on this website (**which is fine**) - but if this is the case, I want the value just to be returned as £0.

Instead I get 'Run-time error '424' Object required.

Which is because my ID "X123" isn't on the website.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
```

Sub getdata()

```
Dim wb As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim sURL As String
Dim getprice As Object
Dim myValue As String


For i = 8 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B34").Value
    Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")

    sURL = Cells(i, 1)
    wb.Navigate sURL
    wb.Visible = False

    Do While wb.Busy = True Or wb.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set getprice = wb.Document.getElementById("X123")

    myValue = getprice.innerText
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = myValue
    wb.Quit
    Set wb = Nothing

Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Make additional check `If Not IsNull(wb.Document.getElementById("X123")) Then ' ... do the stuff ...`.

Comment: @omegastripes - if you put this as an answer then I'l vote for it (this solved it!). I did have to put myValue= 0 just before wb.quit to make sure the value was at least 0 before it went back through the code..

Comment: @Boswell You may upvote any of [such answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20Do%20While%20IsNull).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some error handling

```
On Error Resume Next
Set getprice = wb.Document.getElementById("X123")
On Error GoTo 0

If getPrice Is Nothing Then 
    myValue = "£0"  '<=Assuming £ is included and not formatted in sheet
Else
    myValue = getprice.innerText
End If
```

Comment: Sorry this was working... but then on the 7th iteration it stops working and I get a "run-time error '-2147 [big number... ] automation error"... The debug points me straight to the "    myValue = getprice.innerText" line

Comment: Please include the full error text message. Are you able to print getprice.innerText without the assignment? If so, what is its value? And can you share the URL for the failing case?  It may simply be a case of extending the error handling. I can't anticipate all errors you will encounter so you will want to do some research into basic error handling so you can add your own cases in.

Comment: thanks but the comment in my question ending up working anyway.

Comment: It solved the new issue. My code solved the issue as stated but that is fine.

Comment: You don't have to :-)  But what might be useful is if you add your own answer detailing the final scenario that worked for you and explaining why the additional test was needed. You can always upvote mine if helpful. The general theme of mine is correct which is you needed error handling and I accounted for the case you gave.